# Winograd Convolution

Tags: neural-network, convolution

For https://www.intel.ai/winograd-2/ , why use stride = 2 ?

Why need to transform input image pixels ?

Why [this C++ implementation of winograd convolution](https://github.com/leela-zero/leela-zero/blob/next/src/Network.cpp#L161-L225) does not require any input tensors transformation ?

[image]